# Proper way to share temporary data between two users

Tags: python, django, algorithm, django-rest-framework

Here is my case in django,i need to create a match between two users, users take turn, after one of them has finished, i need to send user1 score to user2 and vise versa.

- How can i create a match between two players?
- How do i store their data(scores) in a way that can be accessed for both users.

Here is what i've tried : user1 sends `GET` request to get a user2 as a opponent by getting user2 id (i can say i made a match there), then after user1 finished he make another `GET` request with his id and score to django. and here is where i stuck :

I don't know how to send user1 score to user2.
I don't know how to store the data so both users can access each other score.

I'm quite new to django, so i did all that based on my basic knowledge of the framework, please correct me if i'm wrong and possibly suggest a better approach.

Comment: i don't have experience in django but there is a lib for temp data , https://pymotw.com/3/tempfile/index.html  may be it can help you ?

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul Thanks i'll take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach I would take would be to create two models one for Match and the other for turn. Match would contain fields including foreign keys to player_1 and player_2 and the overall score, game active and which players turn it is. The second model I would create would be a turn which has the details of the turn and a foreign key to the match.

Each time a turn occurs it would be a CreateView, see [Class based views in the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview). This will create a new turn, and you should be able to automatically add in the game that it belongs to.

The problem you will have then is then notifying the other user that the new turn has been taken. The simplest way would be to just wait and let the user reload the page but that may lead to a subpar user experience.

The next way would be to create a javascript loop to periodically poll your backend and create an alert when the other player has taken their turn.

Finally if you want to do a push from the backend to the browser you will need to investigate [django channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which allows you to setup a websocket connection from the backend to the front end. This will allow you to update your UI as new data is available.

For a new user you might want to progress through the options in the order that has been outlined just to build your experience.

Comment: Thanks, will try your approach and see how its going to be